# Insert data into a JSONB Column using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, jsonb

I have an rails application where I have scaffolded out an entire resource. Now through the UI I am trying to create an record but somehow i have an column in my database which is of type JSONB (Supported by PostGreSQL) whose value is not getting pushed into my table. Can anybody help me out on this as i am relatively new to rails.

Comment: can you update your question with the how you are doing it at the moment ? if you pass a hash with key values to a JSONB it should get saved

Comment: @Shani can you share with me some working code. I dont have any as I am lost on what to do and how to do

Comment: Is there a seperate type of form builder object that I have to use to accept my input for JSONB Column. Currently I am making use of a text field wherein I type the input data

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your intention of using the jsonb through the form.
you normally save a hash in jsonb column. So if you put hash like following in your text field it should get saved. 
[{name: 'Jone', lastname: 'Doe'}].

Hope that helps